# Oracle: Count of New Users from Transactions table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table
Table: Sales

[image: Table: Sales]

I Need to write Oracle SQL query to identify new customers each day,
when a customer (Customer-X) do 1 new transaction on a specific date(Date-X), customer is considered as new customer only for this date(Date-X), if same customer (Customer-X) makes other transactions after that(Date-Y), then this customer is not considered new customer for any date bigger than Date-X
this customer is only considered new Customer on Date-X and counted 1 time only

[image: Identify New Customer]

I also need to generate the summary result
which is the count of new customers for each day

[image: Summary]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by s_date) = 1
             then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as new_customer
from sales s;
```

You can then aggregate for the summary:

```
select s_date, sum(case when new_customer = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)
from (select s.*,
             (case when row_number() over (partition by user_id order by s_date) = 1
                   then 'Yes' else 'No'
              end) as new_customer
      from sales s
     ) s
group by s_date
```